# Compare between 2 dates variable in Angular

Tags: angular

Can I compare between this 2 dates or do I need to convert one of them?

date1: `2019-07-31T23:00:00`

date2: `Fri Aug 30 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100` (heure normale d’Afrique de l’Ouest)

I'm working with Angular

Answer (score 3):

Without using a 3rd party library, you can create `new Date` objects using both those formats and then simply use `>` comparer to compare them, like this:

```
const date1 = new Date("2019-07-31T23:00:00").getTime();
const date2 = new Date("Fri Aug 30 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100").getTime();

if (this.date1 > this.date2) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting date dynamically from any-other source you can go with date pipe library in angular.

```
  var compare1=this.datepipe.transform(date,'dd/MM/yyyy');

  var compare2=this.datepipe.transform(date,'dd/MM/yyyy');

if (compare1 > compare2) {
   your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a method,

```
compareDate(dateTimeOne: Date, dateTimeTwo: Date): YouReturn {
 if(dateTimeOne.getTime() > dateTimeTwo.getTime()) {
   ....
 }
}
```

If the variables are not date, you can try something like this

```
compareDate(dateTimeOne: string, dateTimeTwo: string): YouReturn {
     if(Date.parse(dateTimeOne) > Date.parse(dateTimeTwo)) {
       ....
     }
    }
```

You can too try this in moment js..

```
moment(Date1).format("YYYY-MM-DD") > moment(Date2).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```